# Upload images via adjusted form and dropzone and codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, upload

Im trying to upload images via dropzone/codeigniter. Unfortantly I dont get the post data to the controller and then to the modal. obviously it's not ajax where i can insert data in order to get it.

Here is part of the form:

```
<div class="dropzone" id="my-dropzone" name="mainFileUploader">
    <div class="fallback">
        <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", { 
    url: "<?=admin_url()?>invoice_items/upload_image",
    data: this,
    method: "post",
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.jpeg,.JPEG,.JPG,.png,.PNG',

    init: function () {
        this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
            console.log(file);
        });
    }
});
```

Here is the controller

```
public function upload_image(){
    if ($this->input->post()) {
        $this->invoice_items_model->add_image($this->input->post());
    }
}
```

Here is the modal

```
public function add_image($data){
    $dat = array(
        'rel_name' => $data['name'],
        'rel_type' => 'cms_items',
        'dateadded' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
    );
    $this->db->insert('tblfiles', $dat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the one that need an answer:

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-dropzone", { 
    url: "<?=admin_url()?>invoice_items/upload_image",
    files: this,
    method: "post",
    addRemoveLinks:true,
    acceptedFiles: '.jpg,.jpeg,.JPEG,.JPG,.png,.PNG',
    init: function (data) {
        this.on("sucess",function(file, xhr, formData){

        });


    },
    dictDefaultMessage: "<?=_l('drop_files_here_to_upload')?>",
    dictRemoveFile : "<?=_l('remove_file')?>"
});
```